# Oracle APEX Warning Message

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I want to create warning message exactly as success.

APEX has the default success message:

apex.message.showPageSuccess('OK');

[image]

So, instead of this success message, i want to create a warning message like this:
[image]

when &AMELIA. < 0.

(AMELIA is an application item).

Now i am using apex.message.alert but it's not the same, because this alert is different:
[image]

Can someone help me to create a warning message instead of this black alert message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paste the below code in the **Function and Global Variable Declearation** section

```
function show_notification(Msg){  
        apex.message.showPageSuccess(Msg); 
        $('#t_Alert_Success').attr('style','background-color: #ffe5ad;');
        $('.t-Alert-title').attr('style','color: black;font-weight: bold;');
        $('#t_Alert_Success div div.t-Alert-icon span').removeClass('t-Icon').addClass('fa fa-warning');
}
```

How to use:

For example:

1. Create a button.
2. Create a Dynamic Action on click of the button
3. Create a True Action and select Javascript Code call the created JS function(shown below)

```
show_notification("Your Message");
```

**NOTE: The color and icon can be changed as per the requirement**

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Akil_Ramesh. I wrote  all the above to javascript code and it works!! Do you know where can i find Function and Global Variable Declearation section?

Comment: function and global variables declaration is a page attribute - you'll find it under page properties

Comment: Thanks! I altered the colors and text styling a bit using APEX own classes: `$('#t_Alert_Success').addClass('u-warning');
        $('.t-Alert-title').attr('style','color: black;font-weight: normal; font-size: 1em;');
        $('#t_Alert_Success div div.t-Alert-icon span').removeClass('t-Icon').addClass('fa fa-2x fa-warning u-danger-text');`